# Помогите с Timer

Tags: java, android

Нужно сымитировать движение планет в солнечной системе. Планеты нарисовал канвой. Нужно задать им движение. Пока что есть 3 планеты. Хочу задать им движение Timer'ом. Не могу сообразить, как сделать вращение планеты по кругу и не понимаю, где именно нужно вызывать schedule.
в программировании новичок

```
public class SolarSystem extends View {

public SolarSystem(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

Paint sun = new Paint();
Paint mercury = new Paint();
Paint venus = new Paint();
Paint ears = new Paint();

Paint circles = new Paint();

boolean stars = true;

int X_Mercury = 700;
int Y_Mercury = 750;
int R_Mercury = 30;
int A_Mercury = 1;



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    if (stars) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
            circles.setColor(Color.rgb(250, 250, 250));
            canvas.drawCircle((float) (Math.random()*1080), (float) (Math.random()*1920), 1, circles);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            circles.setColor(Color.rgb(250, 250, 250));
            canvas.drawCircle((float) (Math.random()*1080), (float) (Math.random()*1920), 3, circles);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            circles.setColor(Color.rgb(250, 250, 250));
            canvas.drawCircle((float) (Math.random()*1080), (float) (Math.random()*1920), 4, circles);
        }
        stars = false;
    }

    circles.setColor(Color.argb(50, 250, 250, 250));
    circles.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    canvas.drawCircle(550, 800, 160, circles);
    canvas.drawCircle(550, 800, 275, circles);
    canvas.drawCircle(550, 800, 425, circles);

    sun.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    canvas.drawCircle(550, 800, 100, sun);

    mercury.setColor(Color.rgb(184, 134, 11));
    canvas.drawCircle(X_Mercury, Y_Mercury, R_Mercury, mercury);

    venus.setColor(Color.rgb(160, 82, 45));
    canvas.drawCircle(650, 550, 45, venus);

    ears.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 128));
    canvas.drawCircle(250, 500, 60, ears);

    start();

}



public void movingMercury(){
    X_Mercury = (int) (700 + 30 * Math.cos(A_Mercury++));
    //cos (t*a)
    Y_Mercury = (int) (750 + 30 * Math.sin(A_Mercury++));
}

Timer tMercury = new Timer();
TimerTask ttMercury = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        movingMercury();
        invalidate();
    }
};

public void start() {
    tMercury.schedule(ttMercury, 100);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Мои извинения, предыдущий ответ был совершенно "не в ту степь".
Попробуйте заменить invalidate на postInvalidate(). 
Возможно отрисовки нет потому как процесс таймера это не "UIThread"

**UPDATE** Ну и раз уж я накосячил в первом варианте ответа, то решил таки собрать ваш код. Все красиво, советы следующие:

1. Ну конечно в данном случае только postInvalidate
2. Уберите start() из onDraw, плохая практика запускать потоки из перегружаемых методов не зная до конца где и когда эти методы будут вызваны.
3. Ну конечно чтобы постоянно не вызывать старт пользуйте scheduleAtFixedRate
4. Старт вызовете один раз в активити

   ```
    SolarSystem ss = new SolarSystem(this);
    setContentView(ss);
    ss.start();
   ```
5. Не забывайте что Math.cos() принимает аргумент в **радианах** у вас очеь похоже на градусы.

З.Ы. "Звездочки" при отрисовке согласно вашему коду "пропадают", либо уберите условие, либо придется подумать как сохранить первичную рандомную картинку для последующей отрисовки фона...

Comment: Я не совсем уловил вашу мысль. Как сделать поле класса от Viwe

Comment: Полем вашего класса (наследуемого от View) должен стать canvas.

Comment: ага, это понял. а как потом сделать так, чтобы вызывался таймер ? где его вызывать нужно будет?

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё понятно. Уже все сделал и работает.

Comment: а не подскажите, можно ли в методе onDrow добавлять другие вьюшки, например, картинки, кнопки?

Comment: Это onDraw в нем ркализуйте **только** рисование. Все другое будет лишним.